# How to use full join and sum and SQL

Tags: sql-server, join

Coder-newbie using SQL server mgmt studio 2014.  I am trying to complete a full join on two tables:

```
DAILY 
ID| NAME  | DATE      |HEALTH
1 | Tim   |01/01/2016 | 4
2 | George| 01/01/2016| 5
1 | Tim   |02/01/2016 | 8
2 | George| 02/01/2016| 7


TRAINING 
ID| DATE       |   LOAD
1 | 2016-01-01 |    60
1 | 2016-01-01 |    40
1 | 2016-02-01 |    100
2 | 2016-02-01 |    75
```

As you can see from the tables there is *usually* an entry a day per id for     DAILY, however there are often multiple entries per day and id for TRAINING. - Or sometimes none just to confuse things!

I want to join a table that has a single row per date and id and the sum of the    load for that particular date and id. Code so far is below, but I assume I also need a groupby and sum operator in there somewhere.  This is the best I have achieved so far

```
select daily.id, daily.date, health, training.date, load
From daily
full join training
on daily.id = training.id

id  |   date      |health   |date       |load
1   |   2016-01-01| 4       |2016-01-01 |60
1   |   2016-01-01| 4       |2016-01-01 |40
2   |   2016-01-01| 5       |NULL       |NULL
1   |   2016-01-02| 8       |NULL       |NULL
2   |   2016-01-02| 7       |NULL       |NULL
NULL|   NULL      |NULL     | 2016-02-01|100
NULL|   NULL      |NULL     |2016-02-01 |75
```

Whereas the first row I would actually want to look like this:

```
id  |   date      |health   |date       |load
1   |   2016-01-01| 4       |2016-01-01 |100
```

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it as I am getting tangled up in newbie coding knots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT daily.id, daily.date, daily.health, SUM(training.load)
FROM daily
LEFT JOIN training
ON daily.id = training.id
AND daily.date = training.date
GROUP BY daily.id, daily.date, daily.health
```

Lmk if this doesn't compile or give the right result for some reason.

Comment: You may notice that when Stack Overflow formats the query, it puts `load` in blue. It goes blue because it's a reserved word in SQL Server. If you encounter any issue, you may want to give that column a different name (that doesn't potentially conflict with SQL's own names).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: Big step forward - now I get this:

Comment: <Sorry, got timed out writing the following>  however it does not return the load values for ID#2 on the 2/1/2016 which should be 75.  I assume this is because there is nothing to sum?  Or is it because it is a left join? I was debating the different types of join to use and still wonder if I need a full join.  It is possible my data will have a date that exists for a given ID in the right table but not the left.  However a full join doesn't return the table I need either.....

Comment: It might be related to how you're formatting those dates. Your join needs an exact match of dates on both sides. I can see in your output there are sometimes spaces in front of dates. And you have two contrasting date formats (2016-02-01 and 02/01/2016). This can give undesired results. I can't even tell you how it will join up those dates without knowing the data type for those columns in the table, and your locale settings in the DB. (In some countries 02/01/2016 means 1st of Feb, and in other countries 2nd of Jan).

Comment: Perfect, sorted out the date issue and first run of it seems to work!  Now to test it with a larger dataset.  Many thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it's working now. That is great to hear. Could you take a minute to update this answer to accepted?